# How to work with exclusive and shared FE, BE databases

Tags: ms-access, frontend, backend

I want to open the FE of my application in exclusive mode so that I do not open again the same application in the same machine but I need to open the BE in shared mode which is located in a server.
How do I set the whole thing? I want to the FE to open by itself in exclusive mode always and in case the user tries to open it a 2nd time to display an error that the DB is being used by the same user.

Comment: Did you try? The backend will be opened as shared.

Comment: I assume backend is opened as shared, but I do not know how to check or how to force the FE to open exclusive by default. any clue?

Comment: For the frontend, use the /exclusive option. For the backend, try opening it directly with Access.